# What does a bang before a variable do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am reading through the RoR guide on testing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

About 1/5th down the page it says ""To see how a test failure is reported, you can add a failing test to the post_test.rb test case."

```
test "should not save post without title" do
  post = Post.new
  assert !post.save
end
```

I am trying to understand what the use of the bang (!) before post save means.

In an app that I am developing I have a validattion in the model for post

```
validates :post, presence: true
```

- If I leave the line as it is, the test passes.
- If I remove the bang the test fails (because of the validation)
- If I move the bang to after the save an exception is raised (because the validation fails
  and the bang returns the error message, I think)

So can you help me understand please, what does the bang in front do nd why does it make the test pass?

**Question edit / extension**: Why is the second test a fail (F) and not an exception (E)

Comment: Excites it. But seriously, it's a standard Ruby operator, and is found across languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bang (!) inverts the result of `post.save`

`assert post.save` reads assert that the post **does** save

`assert !post.save` reads assert that the post **doesn't** save

Check out the Ruby Logical Operators section at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

**Edit for extended question:**

`assert` looks for a true result. If the result is true, it returns a pass for that test. If the result is not true, it returns a fail for that test.

Some pseudo code for the `asset` method,

```
def assert(result)
  if result == true
    return 'Pass'
  else
    return 'Fail'
  end
end

assert true

=> 'Pass'

assert false

=> 'Fail'
```

If there is an exception in the test or code, the `test` method will rescue the exception and return (E).

Some pseudo code for the `test` method,

```
def test(description, &block)
  begin
    yield
  rescue
    return 'Exception'
  end
end

test 'test description' do
  raise 'An error occurred'
end

=> 'Exception'
```

Comment: OMG!! How incredibly obvious. ha ha Just when I think I am cracking this nut I am reminded how much of a n00b I am. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: No worries. I've updated answer for extended question

Comment: Sam,Thank you again. Very helpful. I am not sure I understand why the second one doesn't thrown the exception though. Aren't the second (save) & third (save!) both trying to write to the database and failing the validation?

Comment: Apologies I found the answer here (in case anyone else finds it useful) http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save. "There’s a series of callbacks associated with save. If any of the before_* callbacks return false the action is cancelled and save returns false."

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the Logical Not prefix operator - it is not related to variables or methods.

It can be summarized as:

```
x            !x
---------    ---------
nil          true
false        true
true         false
<other>      false
```

(In this case `x` is the result of evaluating `post.save`.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is correct but Sam go in before you.